# NoMethodErrors when accessing methods of Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

When I run Cucumber I get the following errors:

```
undefined method `visit' for "default":String (NoMethodError)
C:/Users/user/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:157:in `visit'
C:/Users/user/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:in `visit'
D:/Andrey/project/features/support/env.rb:33:in `basicAuth'
D:/Andrey/project/features/support/env.rb:54:in `addHost'
D:/Andrey/project/features/support/env.rb:95:in `Before'
```

when invoking `Capybara.visit("http://www.google.com")` and

```
undefined method `browser' for "default":String (NoMethodError)
D:/Andrey/project/features/support/env.rb:105:in `After'
```

when invoking `page.driver.browser.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")`

and many similar errors. It seems that everywhere methods of capybara aren't accessible.

But when I run `Capybara.methods.sort`, I get [output](https://gist.github.com/3239428) that includes visit.

Why does it happen?

**Update:**
Problem was in env.rb. It contained code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
  end
end
```

If I change it to:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
  end
end
```

Then it works.

What's wrong with previous code?

Comment: If you need another information, I'll be happy to give it.

Comment: Can we see your `env.rb` please?

Comment: @Dougui I've updated a question

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['network.proxy.http'] = 'localhost'
profile['network.proxy.http_port'] = 9090

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
```

It it doesn't work, try to do this :

```
visit("http://www.google.com") #remove "Capybara" before
```